how can I update a video by new one selected from pc by using input file, in react js?
I am trying to update the 'src' of video tag by updating state variable. In state variable I am storing the video file which I am selecting from my pc using file input.
I have tried it by using FileReader, it creates a URL for newly selected video and video tag's src attribute also being assigned new URL but when I try to play that video it does not play. I have tried it in rect js. I am sharing my code below:
I just want that when I select video form my PC using file input then that select video file should ne play in video tag I have created.
function EditProfile() {
    const handleVideoChange = (event) => {
        const file = event.target.files[0];
        setSelectedVideo(file);
    
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (event) => {
          setProfileVideo(event.target.result);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    };

    const handleSave = () => {
        // setProfileVideo(selectedVideo);
        console.log("profileVideo : ",profileVideo);
        setVisible2(!visible2);
    };


  return (
    <>
       
   
                                                <div className='user-bio-video-clip mt-lg-0 mt-4'>
                                                    <VideoPlayer
                                                        videoUrl={profileVideo}
                                                        width='100%'
                                                    />

                                                    <Link className='edit-bio-video-clip' onClick={() => setVisible2(!visible2)}>
                                                        Edit Video
                                                    </Link>
                                                </div>
        {/* modals to update video */}
        <CModal
            className='photos-upload-modal'
            alignment="center"
            visible={visible2}
            onClose={() => setVisible2(false)}
            aria-labelledby="VerticallyCenteredExample"
            size='lg'
        >
            <CModalBody>
                <div className='upload-photo-modal-body-content film-upload-content text-center'>
                    <h3>upload your video</h3>
                    <div className='text-center mt-4'>
                        <label htmlFor='photoInput' className='secondary_outline_btn'>
                            Browse
                        </label>
                        <input type='file' id="photoInput" onChange={handleVideoChange} accept="video/*" hidden/>
                    </div>
                    <div className='mt-4'>
                        <CButton className='primary_btn' onClick={handleSave}>
                            Save
                        </CButton>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <CButton className='close_modal_btn' onClick={() => setVisible2(false)}></CButton>
            </CModalBody>
        </CModal>

       
    </>
  )
}

export default EditProfile;


You are not getting an Answer because your problem cannot be reproduced. Your shown code is not doing "I have tried it by using FileReader, it creates a URL for newly selected video and video tag's src attribute" ... Did you use createObjectURL anywhere in some part of your other (un-shown) code?

Also possible issue with a return setup like: <> ...<div> code  </div> </>  .... maybe try to make those empty tags <> and </> into empty divs like <div> and </div> in order to return a "master" div that contains the other divs and code inside them.
